# Issue with CSS Grid & Margin

Tags: html, css

When I add `margin` to my grid, due to `width` of the grid elements being 33.33% the sections stack vertically.

Also I don't want to use any framework (I'd like to do thisjust by using custom CSS).

[Example Website](https://yashgulati.github.io/coursera-test/module2-solution/)

Comment: i am trying to set margin between the sections, doing so aligns my third section to new line.

Comment: Then decrease the width and assign the margin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: If you want to add margins to your divs without them pushing to the next line you will need to reduce your width of the divs.

Comment: how much to decrease? so that distant between first and second remains same as second and third in screen size above 992px

Comment: do some calculation.. Like if total width is 100%, margin b/w divs is 5%(2*5% =10%) then 90% is remaining to be assigned as with which can be equally divided to div i.e. 30% each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more wrap around your divs to make your own grids.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}
.container {
  padding: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
section {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.section-content {
  background-color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section-content > h3 {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  clear: both;

}
.section-content > p {
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}

div>section:nth-child(1) h3{ background-color: #D59898; }
div>section:nth-child(2) h3{ background-color: #C14543; color: white; }
div>section:nth-child(3) h3{ background-color: #E5D198; }
@media(min-width: 992px){
  section{
    width: 33.33%;

  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="section-content">
      <h3>Chicken</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad miluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  quis nostrud exer.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="section-content">
      <h3>Beef</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamc nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate veit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="section-content">
      <h3>Sushi</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vo  quis nostrud exer quis nostrud exer.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: why I am not able to apply the margin to the sections in the code you gave?

Comment: snippet is working fine but in my browser there is no margin and gray color is totally gone.

Comment: @YashGulati Bcz margin are external indents. If used margin then actual width of element will be width(33.33%) + margin.

Answer (score 7):

When you use `margin` with elements that have a `%` width, it adds whatever the `margin` value is, to the `%`.

For example if you have elements that are `33%` wide and add `10px margin` to those elements; your elements are `33% + 10px` which makes them **wider than 33%**.

Use `padding` instead (and [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp_)

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ee55Le6z/)**

Answer (score 1):

As margin is added on top of element width your combined width of 3 elements is more than 100% that is why your element goes into next row. You can lower your element width so that is 100% added with margins. Or don't use margins.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your three columns lets say like this

```
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

As soon as you add margin or padding to them they will push the one furthest to the right down a line. Reason being is at 33.3% wide already there is no space to extend them any further because it then goes over 100%.

If you were to do this

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="inner" style="padding:10px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="inner" style="padding:10px;"></div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="inner" style="padding:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Then all the content in the `.inner` div would have the padding applied to it so that the content wouldn't appear to touch the contents in the next `.col-md-3` beside it.

Here is a fiddle illustrating the point further https://jsfiddle.net/mak9te5c/

Comment: But as soon you add a border around it, it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: If you put the borders on your .col-md-3 then no, because they are exactly 1/3 of the available width. But it works just fine if you add the border to the inner class. https://jsfiddle.net/5q2v1ksy/